# updating player score using threads

Tags: android

I'm trying to update the score using threads so that when the score is greater than or equal to 4 the next level button background is changed.

Here is the code Lylevel1 (Lyrics Level 1)

```
public class Lylevel1 extends Activity {
List<Question> quesList;
int score=0;
int qid=0;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
Button butNext;
ImageButton v1;
ImageView v2;
Button b2;
  protected Lyricswho context;
    //add a constructor with the Context of your activity
    public Lylevel1(Lyricswho _context){
        context = _context;
    }

public MediaPlayer mp = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lylevel1);
   AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    Dblyrlevel1 db=new Dblyrlevel1(this);
    quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
    txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    v1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    v1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
      // v2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      //  b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);




    setQuestionView();

    butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.stop();
                mp = null;
            }
                v1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER() + " " + answer.getText());



                if (answer.getText().equals(currentQ.getANSWER())) {

                    score++;
                    Log.d("score", "Your score" + score);
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong! Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();

                  // Set/Store data
                 edit.putInt("score1", score);
                edit.commit();


        final int score1 = pref.getInt("score1", 0);
        context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

            if (score1 >= 4) {

               b2.getBackground().setAlpha(150);
       v2.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);

    }
```

}
});

This activity is trying to change button controls of activity "Levelwho" (group of buttons from level 1 to level 10) so when score of lylevel1 is >= 4 the button's background of lylevel2 is changed automatically. But when I click on lylevel1 button the app crashes. Any help?

[image]

anyone who can answer this??? I'm stuck at this point for a week :/

Comment: If you'll post the LOGCAT, it will be much easier helping you.

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad logCat added.

Comment: @Udil updated with logCat.

Answer (score 0):

Your score reference is declared final:

```
final int score1 = pref.getInt("score1", 0);
```

so that value will never update.

What should fix it is:
1) Make the "preferences" object the "final" value that you reference in the runnable.
2) Get the value of score1 within your runnable object.

Even better, at the point where you create your runnable, you already know the value of "score", so why not put that in an "if" block in that function and only call the runnable if the score is the correct value (and don't even run that runnable on the ui thread if the score hasn't just been set to the correct value).

Comment: I'm using socre1 because it is stored in the shared preference file so the next time the user try to play the game the button's background is the same i.e unlocked. I will try with the final thing thanks for the tip :)